# What is the fast way to send response to the client and then run long/heavy actions in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out, what is the best/fast way to send the response from `expressjs` and then do log or do long actions in the server, without delaying the response to the client.

I have the following code, but I see that the response to the client is send only after the loop is finished. I though that the response will be send because I'm triggering `res.send(html);` and then calling `longAction`

```
function longAction () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
    console.log('Finish');
}

function myfunction (req, res) {
    res.render(MYPATH, 'index.response.html'), {title: 'My Title'}, (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
            re.status(500).json({'error':'Internal Server Error. Error Rendering HTML'});
        }
        else {
            res.send(html);
            longAction();            
        }
    });
}


router.post('/getIndex', myfunction);
```

What is the best way to send the response and then run my long/heavy actions?
Or What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to figure out, what is the best/fast way to send the response from expressjs and then do log or do long actions in the server, without delaying the response to the client.

The best way to do this is to only call `longAction()` when express tells you that the response has been sent.  Since the response object is a stream, you can use the `finish` event on that stream to know when all data from the stream has been flushed to the underlying OS.

From the [writable stream documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish):

> The 'finish' event is emitted after the stream.end() method has been called, and all data has been flushed to the underlying system.

Here's how you could use that in your specific code:

```
function myfunction (req, res) {
    res.render(MYPATH, 'index.response.html'), {title: 'My Title'}, (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({'error':'Internal Server Error. Error Rendering HTML'});
        }
        else {
            res.on('finish', () => {
                longAction();            
            });
            res.send(html);
        }
    });
}
```

---

For a little more explanation on the `finish` event, you can start by looking at the [Express code for `res.send()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L221) and see that is ends up calling `res.end()` to actually send the data.  If you then look at the [documentation for `.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback) on a stream writable, it says this:

> Calling the writable.end() method signals that no more data will be written to the Writable. The optional chunk and encoding arguments allow one final additional chunk of data to be written immediately before closing the stream. If provided, the optional callback function is attached as a listener for the 'finish' event.

So, since Express doesn't expose access to the callback that `.end()` offers, we just listen to the `finish` event ourselves to be notified when the stream is done sending its last bit of data.

---

Note, there is also a typo in your code where `re.status(500)` should be `res.status(500)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use setImmediate :

```
var test = function(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
    console.log('Finish');
}

router.get("/a", function(req, res, next){
    setImmediate(test);
    return res.status(200).json({});
});
```

Your long function will be executed at the end of the current event loop cycle. This code will execute after any I/O operations (in this sample, first I/O operation is the res.status(200)) in the current event loop and before any timers scheduled for the next event loop.

Comment: This assumes that the response is all sent on one tick of the event loop.  That may or may not be true.  If the response to be sent is large and/or the link to the client is slow, it may not all get sent on one tick of the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers:

After checking I think the best approach is using listening to `finish` event

```
res.on('finish', () => {
    // Do another stuff after finish got the response
});
```